# Printing from Chrome - what does "Fit to page" actually do?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, printing

I'm trying to generate a PDF that will be printed onto headed paper, and I need to line up the content I'm printing with some of the pre-printed content.

If I generate the PDF and open it in a reader like Foxit, it prints fine, but when it's opened and printed from Chrome, the "Fit to page" checkbox is checked by default and the PDF is scaled, so it no-longer fits with the pre-printed content.

What I'd like to know is what the Fit to page feature is actually trying to do. I'd like to generate a PDF that Chrome doesn't feel the need to scale, but I'm not sure if it is scaling based on the margins, the paper size or something else.

The PDF page-size matches the paper being used, and I've tried adjusting the margins, but nothing seems to work.